# In linked list, program shuts down when entering the struct's member

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc

Though I changed malloc to every struct's members, it shuts down before entering members. I think it is a memory problem, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

```
struct player {
    int num;
    char name[40];
    int age;
    int Amatch;
    int goals;
    struct player* next;
};
```

This is struct code.

```
printf("Enter the number of players: ");
scanf("%d", &player_num);

ptr = (struct player*)malloc(sizeof(struct player));
if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error!");
    return 0;
}

ptrW = ptr;
ptrWW = ptr;

for (int j = 0; j < player_num; j++) {
    if (j != 0) {
        ptr = (struct player*)malloc(sizeof(struct player));
        if (ptr == NULL) {
            printf("Error!");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    ptr->num = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (ptr->num == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    strcpy(ptr->name ,(char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 40));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    ptr->age = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (ptr->age == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    ptr->goals = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (ptr->goals == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    ptr->Amatch = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (ptr->Amatch == NULL) {
        printf("Error!");
        return 0;
    }
    if (j == player_num - 1) {
        ptr->next = NULL;
    }
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

This is how I get malloc. I'm also curious there is simpler way to get malloc.

```
while (ptrW != NULL) {
    printf("**Player%d**\n", i);
    printf("Number : ");
    scanf("%d", ptrW->num);
    printf("Name : ");
    scanf(" ");
    gets_s(ptrW->name, sizeof(ptrW->name));
    printf("Age: ");
    scanf("%d", ptrW->age);
    printf("A-matches : ");
    scanf("%d", ptrW->Amatch);
    printf("Goals : ");
    scanf("%d", ptrW->goals);
    printf("\n");
    i++;
    ptrW = ptrW->next;
}
```

Here's the problem. It executes well when entering the player1's members, but before the entering the player2's num, the program shuts down.

Comment: You only need to malloc space that is pointed to by a pointer, not every variable. Turning on your compiler warnings will tell you A LOT of mistakes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to allocate space for the structure itself, and not the member variables in this case.

```cpp
ptr = (struct player*)malloc(sizeof(struct player));
if (ptr == NULL) {
    printf("Error!");
    return 0;
}
```

You should also specify the address of the variable in the calls to scanf.

```cpp
    scanf("%d", &ptrW->num);
    scanf("%d", &ptrW->age);
    scanf("%d", &ptrW->Amatch);
    scanf("%d", &ptrW->goals);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
I think that you should use realloc when j!=0.
You won’t lose the data of you string.
Secondly: malloc/realloc/calloc are function that we use to allocate a block of memory and you can use them only on pointer (after the allocation the pointer will point at the first case of the block)
Third: function strcpy() need to copy from a string - when you use malloc into strcpy() -> the compiler doesn’t know what to copy (no value into the block of the allocation).
Hope that it helped